# IPHONE - groups and folders

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a folder structure that I would like to have in my bundle.

If I create groups on Xcode and drag files to them, these groups are not real folders and the files will be all placed at the same place.

Then I tried dragging the folders from finder directly to the project on Xcode. This time, folders were created inside the project structure, but when I compile the application, the final executable doesn't contain the file structure and all files are scattered on the same place. The problem is that when I try to access a directory as I have created, the app crashes, because the final app doesn't have them.

How do I force Xcode to generate a final executable that contains this structure of directories?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the directory with the Finder, and drag it to XCode.
In the dialog, choose «Folder reference», instead of «group». It will tell XCode it's a real directory.
Finally, also ensures the directory is added to the «Copy files» build phase of your application's target.